# Wait until Firestore data is retrieved

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> I need after inner foreach finish and add all data in list then send to interface
>
> but when but this line  " view.setOrders(orderList); " below "  orderList.add(order); "
>
> my code run okye but not that is not performance , I need best way to collection list then send to interface ..

```
public ListenerRegistration getOrders() {

        view.showLoading();

       ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration = refOrders.addSnapshotListener((queryDocumentSnapshots, e) -> {

            view.hideLoading();

            if (e != null) {
                view.onErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            } else {
                List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                    Order order = snapshot.toObject(Order.class);
                    order.setOrderId(snapshot.getId());

                    refUsers.document(order.getPhone()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                User user = task.getResult().toObject(User.class);
                                order.setName(user.getName());
                                order.setAddress(user.getAddress());
                                orderList.add(order);

                            }


                        }
                    });
                }

                //Here Back List size = 0
                view.setOrders(orderList);


            }
        });

       return listenerRegistration;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `get()` method is asynchronous which means that the code after the `CompletionListener` will be executed **first** and then after the data is retrieved the `listener` will get executed.

Therefore to solve the issue add the following line `view.setOrders(orderList);` inside the `CompletionListener`

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
 User user = task.getResult().toObject(User.class); 
 order.setName(user.getName());
 order.setAddress(user.getAddress());
 orderList.add(order);
view.setOrders(orderList);
```

Comment: I was try that , this is not performance . If I have 10 order why I send list 10 time ,,

Comment: What? This is the only to not get an empty list. What are you sending 10 times? You are retrieving here... Just add showloading before retrieving and hideloading after

Comment: Problem If items are removed in list , the last item remains in recyclerview but when make refresh my activity , recyclerview will be empty . that is I mean this way not performance .. I need call view.setOrders(orderList); after end for loop not in for loop ..